# Can't add double quotes to file's directory

Tags: r

I need to get this result having this format :

`"hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_1ELPC | grep "^d" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 "`

So I tried to use this instruction :

`paste0("hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_","1ELPC",cat(" grep \"^d\" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 "),sep = "")`

But, this return

`grep "^d" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 [1] "hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_1EPSE"`

So, the problem is about using the **cat** function, In fact I need that its result will be in quoted format. In other way, I can't understand why the result was inversed here ?

Comment: do you mean `cat(paste0("hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_", "1ELPC", " grep \"^d\" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 ", sep = ""))`?

Comment: `cat` **always** returns `NULL`. I have just tried substituting `sprintf` for `cat` and it seems to work.

Comment: @Sotos, No I need only to get the result of `cat(" grep \"^d\" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 ")` in quoted format. In other words, I need to get his " grep "^d" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 ". this is way I used `cat(" grep \"^d\" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 ")`

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I tried also `sprintf`, but it doesn't work also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you split up the arguments to `paste0` for a specific reason. As @RuiBarradas mentions - `cat` is for printing, but not returning an actual object (always returns `NULL`):

```
paste0("hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_",
       "1ELPC",
       " grep \"^d\" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 ",
       sep = "")
```

returns:

```
[1] "hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_1ELPC grep \"^d\" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 "
```

which looks to me like what you want.

Do note that, in the output `\"` is one character (a double quote). i.e.,

```
> nchar("\"")
[1] 1
```

To further illustrate the point:

```
temp <- paste0("hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_",
               "1ELPC",
               " grep \"^d\" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 ",
               sep = "")

> cat(temp)
hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_1ELPC grep "^d" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8 

> print(temp, quote = FALSE)
[1] hadoop fs -ls -d -C -t /hdfs/data/t1/t11/34/1EX4/ | grep indicateurs-PUB_1ELPC grep "^d" | sort -k6,7 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f8
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if you look carefully, you can see that I need `"^d"` and not   `\"^d\"`.

Comment: yes, that's why I mentioned `\"` being one character, I've updated the post to further illustrate what I was trying to communicate.